# RX - Distinct error with custom IEqualityComparer

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a polling-based protocol and I want to take advantage of RX to transform it in a push-based one. Every x seconds I ask for Tags (name and value) using the protocol, and I get them back from it.

I'm only interested to change of values in tags, and so I'm using DistinctUntilChanges function.

```
this.TagsChangeNotifier = _tags
    .Select(tag => 
    { 
        return Observable
            .Interval(ts)
            .Select(_ => { return tag; })
            .DistinctUntilChanged(new DataTagComparer()); 
    })
    .Merge();
```

And here is the DataTagcomparer class.

```
public class DataTagComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataTag>
{

    public bool Equals(DataTag x, DataTag y)
    {
            b = y.WeakRawValue.ToByteArray().SequenceEqual(x.WeakRawValue.ToByteArray());

        return b;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataTag obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

But looks like unable to work, because I can never see a comparison between 2 different values.
Here is an example.

```
Start program: DataTag("Test",1)
Equals called: x = ("Test",1), y = ("Test",1)
```

Wait 10 seconds and change from protocol to return 2 instead of 1.

```
Equals called: x = ("Test",1), y = ("Test",1)
Equals called: x = ("Test",2), y = ("Test",2)
Equals called: x = ("Test",2), y = ("Test",2)
Equals called: x = ("Test",2), y = ("Test",2)
```

and so on.

The strange part is that is completely missing the comparing between previous and current value!
Do you know what may be the problem?
Actually I'm working with this awful workaround

```
public class DataTagComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataTag>
{

    private object val;

    public bool Equals(DataTag x, DataTag y)
    {
        bool b = true;

        if (val != null)
            b = val.ToByteArray().SequenceEqual(x.WeakRawValue.ToByteArray());

        val = x.WeakRawValue;

        return b;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataTag obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Thank you for your attention,
Vincenzo.

EDIT: DataTag class code

```
public abstract class DataTag
{
    public DataTag(string _Name, string Desc)
    {
        Name = _Name;
        Description = Desc;
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public abstract object WeakValue { get; }
    public abstract object WeakRawValue { get; }
}
```

EDIT: Tag update function

```
this.timerHandle = Observable.Interval(ts).Select(_ => { Update(); return _; }).Publish().Connect();
```

Comment: What is the definition for `DataTag`? (Or as simplified a version as you can paste in that still acts this way)

Comment: Done, it's the full version.

Answer (score 1):

This....doesn't look right, based on your description - although I could be misinterpreting you...

```
this.TagsChangeNotifier = _tags
    // for each tag value in tags...
    .Select(tag => 
    { 
        // Tick off every TimeSpan ts, then...
        return Observable.Interval(ts)
            // Say we've "ticked"
            .Do(tick => Console.WriteLine("It's time to tick!"))
            // Return the value "tag" (which remains constant...)
            .Select(_ => { return tag; })
            // Say what we see
            .Do(t => Console.WriteLine("I see a {0}!", t))
            // But only when it's different from the last one
            // (but we never change the value?)
            .DistinctUntilChanged(new DataTagComparer()); 
    })    
    // And mash them all together into one stream
    .Merge();
```

I suppose it all depends on what `_tags` is, and to some degree what the definition of `DataTag` is, but I don't think this is what you actually want.

EDIT:

Let's draw out the flow - starting with `_tags`, which for the moment I'll assume is an `IObservable`:

```
Time   _tags
  |    tag1
  |    tag2
  |    tag3
```

So far, so good - now for each of those, we `Select` and create an `Interval`:

```
Time   _tags
  |    tag1
  |     \---- Interval
  |
  |    tag2
  |     \---- Interval
  |
  |    tag3
  |     \---- Interval
  |
```

And we tick for a while, reselecting the tag each time:

```
Time   _tags
  |    tag1
  |     \---- Interval
  |            \-------Tick -> tag1
  |            \-------Tick -> tag1
  |            \-------Tick -> tag1
  |    tag2
  |     \---- Interval
  |            \-------Tick -> tag2
  |            \-------Tick -> tag2
  |            \-------Tick -> tag2
  |    tag3
  |     \---- Interval
  |            \-------Tick -> tag3
  |            \-------Tick -> tag3
  |            \-------Tick -> tag3
  |
```

Then we add the `DistinctUntilChanged`:

```
Time   _tags
  |    tag1
  |     \---- Interval
  |            \-------Tick -> tag1 ---> tag1
  |            \-------Tick -> tag1 -X
  |            \-------Tick -> tag1 -X
  |    tag2
  |     \---- Interval
  |            \-------Tick -> tag2 ---> tag2
  |            \-------Tick -> tag2 -X
  |            \-------Tick -> tag2 -X
  |    tag3
  |     \---- Interval
  |            \-------Tick -> tag3 ---> tag3
  |            \-------Tick -> tag3 -X
  |            \-------Tick -> tag3 -X
  |
```

And finally we `Merge` the sub streams:

```
Time   _tags                                      Output
  |    tag1                                         |
  |     \---- Interval                              |
  |            \-------Tick -> tag1 ---> tag1       tag1
  |            \-------Tick -> tag1 -X              |
  |            \-------Tick -> tag1 -X              |
  |    tag2                                         |
  |     \---- Interval                              |
  |            \-------Tick -> tag2 ---> tag2       tag2
  |            \-------Tick -> tag2 -X              |
  |            \-------Tick -> tag2 -X              |
  |    tag3                                         |
  |     \---- Interval                              |
  |            \-------Tick -> tag3 ---> tag3       tag3
  |            \-------Tick -> tag3 -X              |
  |            \-------Tick -> tag3 -X              |
  |
```

So, if all you need to do is catch when the stream of values changes, you can try something shaped like this:

```
// my fake source of "tags", in this case simple strings
var subject = new Subject<string>();
var source = subject.Publish().RefCount();

// Still want to track "distinct chains"
var distincts = source.DistinctUntilChanged();
// But we also want to "look into the future", and see the *next* distinct chain
var futureDistincts = source.DistinctUntilChanged().Skip(1);
// A "delta" occurs when a distinct chain ends, so we'll zip the two
// sequences together (since they are "now distinct" and "now + 1", this will mean changes)
var onlyDeltas = distincts
    .Zip(futureDistincts, (before,after) => Tuple.Create(before,after));

using(onlyDeltas.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine))
{
    subject.OnNext("Foo");
    subject.OnNext("Foo");
    subject.OnNext("Foo");
    subject.OnNext("Bar");  // BAM: triggers an output value of (Foo, Bar)
    subject.OnNext("Bar");
    subject.OnNext("Foo"); // BAM: triggers an output value of (Bar, Foo)
}
```

Comment: They will change, because there is another observable that calls an Update function. See the code in edit part.

Comment: @Vincenzo Ok, but how does `Update` affect the value of `tag` above, when it is inside a snapshot? Do you see how the value of the internal created observable above will *never* have changing values?

Comment: I think I see now what you're saying. So what should I change in code to achieve my aim?

Comment: @Vincenzo You just want to catch changes on a stream?

Comment: Yes, I do. I see your flow drawing and I agree with that. The strange is that changing a tag value does not push it on the stream, because the comparison function gets the new value on both x and y

Comment: @Vincenzo Take a look at the quick sample idea I added

Comment: Alternatively, have tags be IObservable of IEnumerable of DataTag, then do set-to-set comparisons...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27504/discussion-between-vincenzo-and-jerkimball)